# Cannot open php-generated subdirectory

Tags: php, directory

I'm having an issue with my code. Basically I can generate and delete a subdirectory in an existing folder. however, when it displays it tries to open the folder without going through the folder its in. Basically:

Main Directory:

generate.php

testCreate.php

testDeleteDir.php

uploads (folder)

- test (php generated folder through above php files)

when I try to access "test," it doesn't go through uploads to get to it. How can i fix this?

PHP CODE:
 test.php:

```
<form action="testCreate.php" method="post">
  Enter the name of Folder: <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="generate">
</form>
<?php
  $path = "./uploads";

  $dir = opendir($path) or die ("unable to open directory");

  while ($file = readdir($dir)){
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "test.php" || $file == "testCreate.php" || $file == "testDeleteDir.php"){
      continue;
    }

    echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a><a href='testDeleteDir.php?dir=$file'> Delete</p><br />";
  }

  closedir($dir);
?>
```

testCreate.php:

```
<?php
  $dir = $_POST['name'];

  mkdir("./uploads/" . $dir, 0777);

  header("location: test.php");
?>
```

testDeleteDir.php:

```
<?php   
  $dir = $_GET['dir'];
  rmdir("./uploads/" . $dir);
  header("location: test.php");
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you simply need to add the path to the link, like this?

```
echo "<a href='$path$file'>$file</a><a href='testDeleteDir.php?dir=$file'> Delete</p><br />";
```

now it reads both the value for path and the file directory

Comment: thanks!! sorry, path already consisted of the extra slash, so i edited that, otherwise the link would be /uploads//newfolder :P thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`readdir()` doesn't include the path of the directory you're reading from, e.g.

```
$fd = opendir('/etc');
echo readdir($fd);
```

would echo out `.`, not `/etc/.`.

Since you're reading only filenames, but reading them from a subdir, you have to include that subdir in your html `href`s:

```
echo "<a href='uploads/$file'>$file[...snip...]
               ^^^^^^^^
```